# JSON converter on azure mobile service queries

Tags: mobile, azure, json.net

One of my tables in Azure Mobile has a column defined as Number. On the client side that column maps to an enum. I have a JSON converter that marshals the enum value to int (code below).

```
class CompletedStateConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(CompletedState);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return CompletedState.NotCompleted;
        int intVal = serializer.Deserialize<int>(reader);
        CompletedState gameCompleted = (CompletedState)intVal;
        return gameCompleted;
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        CompletedState gameCompleted = (CompletedState)value;
        int number = (int)gameCompleted;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, number);
    }
}
```

All worked fine until I needed to make a change in one of the queries I use to read data from that table.

```
data = await App.GameTable
               .Take(15)
               .OrderByDescending(g => g.LastMoveTime)
               .Where(g => g.Completed == CompletedState.NotCompleted)
               .ToListAsync();
```

Notice the where clause that selects the items where the Completed state is NotCompleted (value of 0 in the enum list).

On the backend the query gets translated into string instead of using the number that should be provided by the JSON converter.

Here's the content of query.getComponents()

```
{
  "filters":
    {
      "operator":"And",
      "left":{"queryString":"(Completed eq 'NotCompleted')","args":[],"type":"LiteralExpression"},
      "right":
        {
          "operator":"Or",
          …removed
          "type":"BinaryExpression"
        },
      "type":"BinaryExpression"
    },
  "selections":[],
  "projection":null,
  "ordering":{"LastMoveTime":false},
  "skip":null,
  "take":15,
  "table":"Game",
  "includeTotalCount":false,
  "version":4
}
```

I expected that the query would leverage the JSON converter to convert the enum into the number. Why isn’t it doing so and what should I do to make it work?

Thank you